# Showing Illegal state exception when Adding a calendar event to calendar in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

In my app it has to add a reminder in to the calendar, I have implemented this using blackberry event, but it is throwing Illegal State Exception. Here is the code what I implemented. Please have a look on this and help me what's wrong in this.

```
EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
BlackBerryEvent bbEvent = (BlackBerryEvent) eventList.createEvent();

long sDate ;
long eDate ;
Date date;
date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse("Dec 26, 2011"));
sDate = date.getTime();
date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse("Dec 31, 2011"));
eDate = date.getTime();
bbEvent.addString(Event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, subject);
bbEvent.addString(Event.LOCATION, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, location);
bbEvent.addString(Event.NOTE, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, description);
bbEvent.addDate(Event.START, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, sDate);
bbEvent.addDate(Event.END, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, eDate);
bbEvent.commit();
```

Comment: which line is throwing illegalStateException

Comment: bbEvent.addDate(Event.START, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, sDate);
bbEvent.addDate(Event.END, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, eDate);  here it is throwing exception.

Comment: What is the message from the ISE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);// 1st Change
BlackBerryEvent bbEvent = (BlackBerryEvent) eventList.createEvent();

long sDate ;
long eDate ;
Date date;
date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse("2011-12-26"));// 2nd    Use "yyyy-MM-dd" format 
sDate = date.getTime();
date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse("2011-12-31"));// 3rd
eDate = date.getTime();
bbEvent.addString(Event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, subject);
bbEvent.addString(Event.LOCATION, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, location);
bbEvent.addString(Event.NOTE, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, description);
bbEvent.addDate(Event.START, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, sDate);
bbEvent.addDate(Event.END, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, eDate);


eventList .commit();//4th change
```

Check this i have make 4 changes in your code.

Comment: Now use..

Event bbEvent = eventList.createEvent();

insteadOf

BlackBerryEvent bbEvent = (BlackBerryEvent) eventList.createEvent();

Comment: I found the problem after this statement (date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse("Dec 26, 2011"));) date value is coming like (date Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 America/New_York) ,if I use date.getTime() it returns 0. I dont know why?

Comment: you have to add current time in time.
Because in (date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse("Dec 26, 2011"));) this statement you can not pass time so.

Comment: pass "2011-12-26 12:12:12".
in HttpDateParser.parse();

Comment: dude its working now, but there is a problem. I used this date "2011-12-31", but after parsing I am getting "date Fri Dec 30 19:00:00 America/New_York 2011" . just one day before the date what I am giving.

Comment: Read the documentation for `HttpDateParser` (http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html). Neither `"Dec 26, 2011"`, `"Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 America/New_York"`, nor `"2011-12-31"` are valid HTTP date/time strings that `HttpDateParser` supports.